# Robotframework - Easy way to fix syntax errors of copied Python libraries onto Maven project which uses Maven robotframework plugin

Tags: java, python, robotframework

I am running the robotframework on JVM, using the maven robotframework dependency.(Using Eclipse)
After i copy RequestsLibrary written in Python onto 'Libraries'(PYTHONPATH) folder of Maven project.(https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests/ ), i get loads of syntax errors on the .py files of the RequestsLibrary.

My understanding, Syntax errors are seen because robotframework.jar might have an interpreter that is older compared to the Library built in new version.

Therefore it might be throwing those syntax errors, I have the very recent dependency for robotframework in the POM.

Need help guys.

Answer (score 1):

RobotFramework-requests is not jython compatible yet. It requires Python 2.6 or above while the official robot framework version is still using jython 2.5

You have 2 options:

- Try the latest Robot framework version (still not officially released) - it uses Jython 2.7
- Rebuild the robot framework jar yourself - replacing jython 2.5 with jython 2.7